# Ruby on Rails Error - NoMethodError undefined method `gem_version' for Alchemy:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alchemy-cms

I have installed Ruby on a VPS (OVH hosted).
I have successfully installed [Alchemy-CMS][1]

When trying to access the admin login, I got this error

> **NoMethodError
> undefined method `gem_version' for Alchemy:Module**

> Extracted source (around line #6):
>
> ```
>   include Alchemy::Admin::Locale
>
>   if Alchemy.gem_version <= Gem::Version.new("4.9")
>     before_action { enforce_ssl if ssl_required? && !request.ssl? }
>   end
> ```
>
> Rails.root: /home/debian/alchemyadmin

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if Gem.loaded_specs['alchemy_cms'].version <= Gem::Version.new("4.9")
...
```